# Check if value is a custom taxonomy category name

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy

I'm needing to check a variable and if the slug doesn't match a custom taxonomy's category slug run a function. I can't wrap my head around what I would need to do in order to get the "categories" of a custom taxonomy in an array and check them against a value.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must use get_terms in order to obtain all the "categories" of a custom taxonomy.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms